# "justify-content: space-between" doesn't work?

Tags: css, vuejs2, frontend, element-ui

"justify-content: space-between;" doesn't work

[image: screenshot]

```css
#app {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40.8px;
  border: 1px solid #409EFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  .el-form {
    .el-form-item {
      /deep/ .el-form-item__content {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        .el-input {
          width: 165px;
        }
        .el-button {
          width: 115px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <el-form>
    <el-form-item>
      <el-input placeholder="请输入验证码"></el-input>
      <el-button type="primary">获取验证码</el-button>
    </el-form-item>
  </el-form>
</div>
```

I have provided complete code at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JokerVII/ywozkv0h/17/).

As shown in the iframe,the el-input isn't flush with the main-start edge, and the el-button isn't flush with the main-end edge.

Why doesn't "space-between" work?it works just like "space-around".

Comment: I can assure you that `justify-content: space-between` "works", however if you'd like us to help you debug your specific use of it, you'll need to provide a full replication of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the styling you got from element-ui. this selector should be overridden:

```
.el-form-item__content::after, .el-form-item__content::before {
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
```

To remove this add:

```
 .el-form-item__content {
     &:before, &:after  {
        content: none !important;
     }
  }
```